# Parsing json while executing a curl

Tags: json, bash, parsing, curl

I am doing the following curl request in my bash script to get a coverage report for my build :

```
codeCoverage=$(curl -s $url/job/$jobname/$lastBuildNo/cobertura/api/json?depth=2)
```

This returns a json reponse which looks like this:

```
{
"results": {
    "children": [
        {
            "children": [
                {}
            ],
            "elements": [
                {},
                {}
            ],
            "name": "com.test.web"
        },
        {
            "children": [
                {}
            ],
            "elements": [
                {},
                {}
            ],
            "name": "com.test.web.filters"
        }
    ],
    "elements": [
        {
            "name": "Classes",
            "ratio": 37.75
        },
        {
            "name": "Conditionals",
            "ratio": 11.63969
        },
        {
            "name": "Files",
            "ratio": 42.70073
        },
        {
            "name": "Lines",
            "ratio": 16.937233
        },
        {
            "name": "Methods",
            "ratio": 23.67906
        },
        {
            "name": "Packages",
            "ratio": 50
        }
    ],
    "name": "Cobertura Coverage Report"
}
```

}

I am just interested in the

```
"name": "Lines",
"ratio": 16.937233
```

I can parse the text once I get it and extract that value, but is there any way to just get that value when I make the curl request?

Comment: do you mean the output will be : `Lines, 16.937233 `?

Comment: Ideally I would want just 16.937233

Comment: Your json file is not valid at line 9.

Comment: use [python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for such tasks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the wonderful json util [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq -r '.results.elements[] | select(.name=="Lines").ratio' input.json
```